# VDS - не отправляются POST-ом файлы

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте. Не отправляются файлы post-ом . 
Зашел в  конфиг nginx  и добавил

```
client_body_buffer_size 20M;
```

Теперь только один файл загружается (хотя он весит 30кб). Подскажите, как исправить ? Спасибо

ошибка была `a client request body is buffered to a temporary file`
стала `mod_fcgid: HTTP request length`

Answer (score 0):

Максимальный размер загружаемого файла устанавливается `client_max_body_size`. Сделайте так:

```
client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_max_body_size 50m;
```